# Running gzipped react code giving error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<"

Tags: reactjs, performance, gzip, create-react-app

I created a app on create-react-app template and added this command under script tag in package.json.

```
"postbuild": "find ./build -type f \\( -name \\*.js -o -name \\*.css \\) -exec gzip {} \\;"
```

I can see gzipped js files being created inside *build/static/js* .

Now when i am trying to use `serve -s build` to run my build code, i am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<`  error.